Is it possible to make Microsoft Flow based on an existing flow by simply copy and pasting the flow or saving it under another name?
Is it possible to make Microsoft Flow based on an existing flow by simply copy and pasting the flow or saving it under another name?  I want to make a virtually identical Microsoft Flow with the only difference being the destination Microsoft List that I am using as a database.
This is a short question.  But I think there is not much that needs to be explained.  If you need more clarificiation, please let me know.
There is a "Save" button but I do not see any "Save As" option.

See the screenshots below:
Option 1:

Option 2:
MyFlow => Click on your flow and you see "Save As" option

